# PostgreSQL Query Optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate new IDs for a large table. The ID's have to be *consecutive* and need to *start at 0* (So I can't use sequence). What I come up with so far is the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION genIds() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
   edge RECORD;
   i INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR edge IN SELECT * FROM network LOOP
        UPDATE network SET id = i WHERE id = edge.id;
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN i;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would much rather like to not care about **id = edge.id** since I don't really care about the id's anyway. Is there a way to avoid having count(network) updates?

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: Btw: you _can_ make a sequence start at `0`: `create sequence foo_seq start with 0 minvalue 0;`

Comment: I thought sequences aren't guaranteed to be gapless?

Comment: They are not that's correct (I thought you just didn't want to use them because you couldn't make them start at 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid having count(network) updates?

If your question is: can this done with a single statement instead of a loop, then yes this is possible:

This can be done without a loop in a single statement:

```
with numbered as (
  select id as old_id, 
         row_number() over (order by id) as new_id
  from network
)
update network nt
  set id = nb.new_id - 1 // -1 to start at 0
from numbered nb
where nb.old_id = nt.id;
```